# Intro Sort (Quick Sort + Heap Sort) not persistent?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I tried to implement [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), which starts as a `quicksort` algorithm but changes over to `heapsort` as soon as the recursion depth reached `2 * log(array length)`.

I tried to run it over a small array *(array size = 20)* and count&print the amount of times it used heap or quick sort. The problem is that everytime i run it, i get different stats. E.G first run it used quicksort 6 times and heapsort 6 times, next time it could be 11 and 14 times. Why is that?

Here is my testing class:

```
public class TestClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] myArray = randomIntArray();
    IntroSort.sort(myArray);
}

private static int[] randomIntArray() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int[] newIntArray = new int[20];
    for(int i = 0; i < newIntArray.length; i++){
        newIntArray[i] = rand.nextInt((1000 - 0) + 1) + 0;
     }   
    return newIntArray;
}
```

}

Here is my Intro Sort class:

```
public class IntroSort {

private static int quick = 0;
private static int heap = 0;

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 * Interface to the outer world, takes an array as 
 * parameter, and calculates the max depth allowed.
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
public static void sort(int[] arrayToSort){     
    int depth = ((int) Math.log(arrayToSort.length))*2;
    sort(arrayToSort, depth, 0, arrayToSort.length-1);
    System.out.println("Total QuickSorts: "+quick);
    System.out.println("Total HeapSorts: "+heap);
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 * Sorting loop, decides whether to use quicksort or 
 * heapsort.
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
private static void sort(int[] arrayToSort, int depth, int start, int end){
    int length = arrayToSort.length;
    if(length <= 1){
        return;
    }else if(depth == 0){
        heap++;
        heapSort(arrayToSort, start, end);
    }else{
        if(start >= end)
            return;
        quick++;
        int pivot = arrayToSort[(start + end)/2];
        int index =  partition(arrayToSort, start, end, pivot);
        sort(arrayToSort, depth-1, start, index-1);
        sort(arrayToSort, depth-1, index, end);
    }
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 * Heap sort implementation, taken and modified from 
 * HeapSort.java
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
private static void heapSort(int[] arrayToSort, int start, int end){
    for (int i = end / 2 - 1; i >= start; i--)
        heapify(arrayToSort, end, i);
    for (int i=end-1; i>=start; i--){
        int temp = arrayToSort[start];
        arrayToSort[start] = arrayToSort[i];
        arrayToSort[i] = temp;
        heapify(arrayToSort, i, start);
    }
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 * Heapify implementation, taken and modified from 
 * HeapSort.java
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
private static void heapify(int[] arrayToSort, int n, int i){
    int largest = i;
    int l = 2*i + 1;
    int r = 2*i + 2;
    if (l < n && arrayToSort[l] > arrayToSort[largest])
        largest = l;
    if (r < n && arrayToSort[r] > arrayToSort[largest])
        largest = r;
    if (largest != i){
        int swap = arrayToSort[i];
        arrayToSort[i] = arrayToSort[largest];
        arrayToSort[largest] = swap;
        heapify(arrayToSort, n, largest);
    }
}

/*
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 * Partition for Quick sort implementation, taken and modified from 
 * QuickSort.java
 * ------------------------------------------------------
 */
private static int partition(int[] arrayToSort, int start, int end, int pivot){
    while(start <= end){
        while(arrayToSort[start] < pivot){
            start++;
        }
        while(arrayToSort[end] > pivot){
            end--;
        }
        if(start <= end){
            int temp = arrayToSort[start];
            arrayToSort[start] = arrayToSort[end];
            arrayToSort[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
    return start;
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe because you give it random input?

Comment: Can you explain please @AndyTurner ?

Comment: `myArray` is randomly generated. Would this not mean that it has to do different amounts of work to get that random array into sorted order?

Comment: Oh right, I see. Why didn't I think of that. Thanks a lot @AndyTurner for pointing that out. Just need to do some time comparions to quicksort, hopefully it perfoms faster! If you want you can answer this question so I can upvote&accept.

Comment: @AndyTurner I did some perfomance tests, and Introsort performs worse than Quicksort, shouldnt it be faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myArray` is randomly generated.

This will mean that the algorithm has to do different amounts of work to get that random array into sorted order.

Passing the same array in multiple times will yield the same counts.

Note that by having these as static variables, you have to reset the counts in between invocations; also, it's not safe to use for parallel invocations. You might want to consider alternatives which don't involve such mutable global state.